# Sort a list of key, values where value is dictionary AND sorting needs to be done on STRING value in the dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Here is my list in python:

```
team_map = [('31983', {'team_sdsk_list': [], 'team_name': 'Commercials', 'in_progress': 0, 'completed': 0, 'not_started': 0}),
 ('32935', {'team_sdsk_list': [], 'team_name': 'DL Platform', 'in_progress': 0, 'completed': 0, 'not_started': 0}),
 ('32955', {'team_sdsk_list': [{'sdsk_summary': 'Task - BSDM Product Readiness (MiFIR Transparency Data package)', 'parent_target_launch_date': '2017-08-21', 'parent_sdsk_number': 774079489, 'attributes': [{'status': 'Complete', 'label': 'DL CONTENT<BR>UPDATED'}], 'rep': 'abc', 'parent_sdsk_product_mgr': 'xyz', 'sdsk_number': 1234, 'parent_sdsk_summary': 'Data Package'}], 'team_name': 'BSDM', 'in_progress': 0, 'completed': 1, 'not_started': 0})]
```

I need to sort this list so that the output is ordered alphabetically based on team_name. notice that team_name is a part of the dictionary, which is the 'value' of the list. 
so the output should be this:

```
[('32955', {'team_sdsk_list': [{'sdsk_summary': 'Task - BSDM Product Readiness (MiFIR Transparency Data package)', 'parent_target_launch_date': '2017-08-21', 'parent_sdsk_number': 774079489, 'attributes': [{'status': 'Complete', 'label': 'DL CONTENT<BR>UPDATED'}], 'rep': 'abc', 'parent_sdsk_product_mgr': 'xyz', 'sdsk_number': 1234, 'parent_sdsk_summary': 'Data Package'}], 'team_name': 'BSDM', 'in_progress': 0, 'completed': 1, 'not_started': 0}),
('31983', {'team_sdsk_list': [], 'team_name': 'Commercials', 'in_progress': 0, 'completed': 0, 'not_started': 0}),
('32935', {'team_sdsk_list': [], 'team_name': 'DL Platform', 'in_progress': 0, 'completed': 0, 'not_started': 0})]
```

I tried this:

```
sorted_team_map = sorted(team_map.items(), key=operator.itemgetter('team_name'))
```

but that gives me an error.
Please help me with the sort function.

Comment: Please add the full traceback of the error you're getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your input data is not a dictionary but a `list` of `tuples`. Each `tuple` second element *is* the dictionary you want to use to sort with a given value.

```
sorted_team_map = sorted(team_map, key=lambda x : x[1]['team_name'])
```

no `.items()` and take the second item of the tuple before accessing the key

How to fix such errors in the future ? (How did *I* fix your code ?):

- your first attempt triggers a `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'` error. Which one calls `items()` ?: `team_map`. So `team_map` is a `list` after all, no need for a function to iterate on a list
- once fixed, you get a second error: `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str`. That's because `itemgetter` passed your key to something that isn't a dictionary but a `tuple`. You need to go one level deeper to reach your dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the dictionary stored at the last position in each tuple in the `sorted` key and utilize the value stored for `"team_name"`:

```
team_map = [('31983', {'team_sdsk_list': [], 'team_name':'Commercials', 'in_progress': 0, 'completed': 0, 'not_started': 0}),
  ('32935', {'team_sdsk_list': [], 'team_name': 'DL Platform', 'in_progress': 0, 'completed': 0, 'not_started': 0}),
  ('32955', {'team_sdsk_list': [{'sdsk_summary': 'Task - BSDM Product Readiness (MiFIR Transparency Data package)', 'parent_target_launch_date': '2017-08-21', 'parent_sdsk_number': 774079489, 'attributes': [{'status': 'Complete', 'label': 'DL CONTENT<BR>UPDATED'}], 'rep': 'abc', 'parent_sdsk_product_mgr': 'xyz', 'sdsk_number': 1234, 'parent_sdsk_summary': 'Data Package'}], 'team_name': 'BSDM', 'in_progress': 0, 'completed': 1, 'not_started': 0})]
final_team = sorted(team_map, key=lambda x:x[-1]['team_name'])
```

Output:

```
[('32955', {'team_sdsk_list': [{'sdsk_summary': 'Task - BSDM Product Readiness (MiFIR Transparency Data package)', 'parent_target_launch_date': '2017-08-21', 'sdsk_number': 1234, 'attributes': [{'status': 'Complete', 'label': 'DL CONTENT<BR>UPDATED'}], 'parent_sdsk_number': 774079489, 'parent_sdsk_product_mgr': 'xyz', 'rep': 'abc', 'parent_sdsk_summary': 'Data Package'}], 'completed': 1, 'in_progress': 0, 'team_name': 'BSDM', 'not_started': 0}), ('31983', {'team_sdsk_list': [], 'completed': 0, 'in_progress': 0, 'team_name': 'Commercials', 'not_started': 0}), ('32935', {'team_sdsk_list': [], 'completed': 0, 'in_progress': 0, 'team_name': 'DL Platform', 'not_started': 0})]
```

Comment: that works but can you explain a little more? how the input is not really a dict but a list of tuples with a dict inside in 2nd position?

Answer (score 2):

So you want to sort the `team_map` list based on the `"team_name"` attribute of the dictionary which is the second element in each `tuple`.

To get this, we take `t` (the `tuple`) and take the second element with `t[1]` (the dictionary) and sort based on the `["team_name"]` attribute:

```
sorted(team_map, key=lambda t: t[1]["team_name"])
```

which gives the expected output:

```
[('32955', {'team_name': 'BSDM', 'team_sdsk_list': [{'parent_target_launch_date': '2017-08-21', 'parent_sdsk_number': 774079489, 'parent_sdsk_product_mgr': 'xyz', 'parent_sdsk_summary': 'Data Package', 'sdsk_summary': 'Task - BSDM Product Readiness (MiFIR Transparency Data package)', 'attributes': [{'label': 'DL CONTENT<BR>UPDATED', 'status': 'Complete'}], 'sdsk_number': 1234, 'rep': 'abc'}], 'completed': 1, 'in_progress': 0, 'not_started': 0}), ('31983', {'team_name': 'Commercials', 'team_sdsk_list': [], 'completed': 0, 'in_progress': 0, 'not_started': 0}), ('32935', {'team_name': 'DL Platform', 'team_sdsk_list': [], 'completed': 0, 'in_progress': 0, 'not_started': 0})]
```

---

Note that rather than using the built-in `sorted()` function and assigning the result of this back to `team_map` (which is what I assume you will do). You can also `sort` the list in place with `team_map.sort`.

So you could achieve the same result as above with:

```
team_map.sort(key=lambda t: t[1]["team_name"])
```